# do_rootfs failed while installing gstreamer-1.0 packages

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am facing do`_rootfs` failed while I am installing the package using `yocto` in final image. Tried options like `INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP` but to of no use.

How can I force do_`rootfs` to execute is there any option.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided nearly enough information for anyone to help you.  For example, what failed?  What was/were the error message(s).  INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP likely has nothing to do with your failure.  You could also join #yocto or the yocto-related mail list as an alternative to posting here.

Comment: In log.do_rootfs file i am getting following:ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command  
packagegroup-core-boot gst-plugins-bad-mpegtsdemux opkg gst-plugins-good-avi packagegroup-base-extended gst-plugins-bad-coloreffects gst-plugins-bad-y4mdec' 
returned 255: